# Write data to the end of the executable from within executable itself

Tags: c, linux, executable

I have this funny idea: write some data (say variable of integer type) to the end of the executable itself and then read it on the next run.

Is this possible? Is it a bad thing to do (I'm pretty sure it's :) )? How one would approach this problem?

**Additional**: 
I would prefer to do this with C under Linux OS, but answers with any combination of programming language/OS would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** 
After some time playing with the idea, it became apparent that Linux won't allow to write to a file while it's being executed. However, it allows to [delete](http://linux.die.net/man/3/remove) it. 
My vision of the writing process at this point:

1. make a copy of the program from withing a program
2. append data to the end of the copy
3. make a program to delete itself
4. rename copy to the original name

Will try to implement that as soon as I have some time.

If anyone is interested about how "delete itself" works under Linux - look for info about [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). It's not possible to do this under Windows, as far as I know (might be wrong).

**EDIT 2:** 
Have implemented a working [example](https://gist.github.com/rsht/6d4be2ee4b8abf5fced3b1ec8258ef95) under Linux with C.
It basically use a strategy described above, i.e. appending bits of data to the end of the copy program, deletes itself and renaming program to the original name. It accepts integers to save as single argument in the CLI, and prints old data as well.

This surely won't work under Windows (although I found [some options](https://blog.barthe.ph/2009/02/22/change-signed-executable/) on a quick search), but I'm curious how it's gonna behave under OS X.

Efficiency thoughts:

- Obviously copying whole executable isn't efficient. I guess that something faster is possible with another helper executable that will do the same after program stops executing.
- It's not reusing old space but just appending new data to the end on each run. This can be fixed with some footer reservation process (maybe will try to implement this in the future)

**EDIT 3:** 
Surprisingly, it works with OS X! (ver. 10.11.5, default gcc).

Comment: Are you trying to get your exe flagged by antivirus programs? And trip rootkit trackers? (And some package managers. And ...)

Comment: In an old DOS times it was definitely possible, some old demos/intros used this trick.

Comment: If the system is properly maintained, the program would be store with only root having the right to write to it.

Comment: Sounds like a terrible idea. If there is some specific background, you should provide that information, otherwise your question is likely to be closed soon for multiple reasons.

Comment: @Olaf this is not about any specific task, but rather for fun and learning. Is it bad being curios about things?

Comment: No, but it is bad asking off-topic questions on a Q&A site. Even worse if they are badly researched and thought.

Comment: But how does question about making an executable out of C code become an off-topic question on SO? I was googling this beforehand (without any luck so far) and definitely was thinking about the topic for a few days now.

Comment: I have just felt like this would be an interesting subject and would help learning about executable structure, OS permissions, and so on. If this is indeed an off-topic one - please, let me know why it's considered such. Also would appreciate advice on other places where I could find help on this matter.  Thanks!